# Why do we need to assume continuity in the proof of the chain-rule?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Look at this proof:

[image]

If $f$ is differentiable at $x$, then it must be continuous there too? Does he then need in the hypothesis that $f$ need to be continuous in the entire interval? What if he just assumes that it is differentiable at $x$?
He also does not mention anything about the continuity of $g$?

Comment: We need $f$ differentiable at a point and continuous on an interval around that point. We could require $f$ be differentiable on an interval, but then there would be examples for which the result is true but that don't meet the hypotheses. The chain rule in this formulation has the least restrictive possible set of hypotheses.

Comment: @Nick Thank you! But lets for the sake of argument say that we didn't know continuity on an interval around x, just differentiability at x, would then the proof fail? I mean in the last red line, since t goes to x, then s must still go to y?(since differentiability at x implies continuity at x) So where do we then need the continuity? I mean, do we really need the continuity in mroe than one point(x)?

Comment: Uh, I haven't had my coffee yet so hopefully I'm not lying to you here. The last red line can fail if $f$ is continuous at $x$ and strictly discontinuous at some given point(s) $p\in [a,b]$, $p \neq x$. If you have trouble thinking of an example, let me know and I'll go brew a pot and see what I can do. (If someone wants to turn my comments into an answer, please feel free to do so, but I don't feel as if I deserve reputation for giving such a half-hearted response, personally.)

Comment: @Nick I’m not sure I see how it fails. What’s written there is pretty much the definition of being continuous at $x$, no continuity anywhere else is needed.

Comment: @Nick Thank you very much! I would love to see an example, because I really can't see why it fails. Since since f is differentiable at x, we know that x is continuous there, so as $t \rightarrow x$, it must be that $f(t) \rightarrow f(x)$, hence $s \rightarrow y$(by the other notation). This is what I do not understand, if you could explain it with a counterexample as you offered that would be great.

Comment: The chain rule does hold assuming only that $f$ is differentiable at $x$. This is as formulated in, e.g.,  Bartle and Sherbert's *Introduction to real Analysis*, pg. 162. (I don't see where the proof you give uses the additional assumption.)

Comment: @David Yes, you're right. It was indeed my lack of coffee. As Chris pointed out above, the last line is literally just continuity at $x$. I'm basically wrong all the way down in this comment chain, just proceed to ignore me forever. (In my defense, I learned the chain rule and proof in terms of Bachmann-Landau notation and I've avoided thinking about it in other terms since.)

Comment: @DavidMitra thanks, and thanks Nick and Christopher Creutzig also!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's superfluous, $s\to y$ by the continuity of $f$ at $x$ which is guaranteed by $f'(x)$.

One could state the theorem like this:

> Let $f$, $g$ be real functions and let there be $x\in\mathbb R$ s.t. $f'(x)$ and $g'(f(x))$ exist. Then $(g\circ f)'(x)=g'(f(x))\cdot f'(x)$.

All the things like $g$ being defined on an interval containing $f(x)$ and $f$ being continuous at $x$ are implicit.

Comment: And by the derivatives existing I mean being finite. Perhaps there's also a version of this with one or both of them being $\pm\infty$, but I don't remember the details.